# Designing Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

How should I design a `Relative Layout` containing `TextViews` as shown in Image below.

I tried in many ways but **TextView2** was not getting below **TextView1**.

Is it possible to draw all the TextViews within 1 Relative Layout.

**PS** - I have to use Relative Layout, as have to use Right of.

Thank You
[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you have problems, the layout is very simple to make.

Comment: Can you post what have you done, because I do not see a problem with using of `layout_below` for the second text.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

- TV2 - layout_below TV1 and align parent left
- TV3 - layout_below TV1 and right of TV2
- TV4 - layout_below TV2 and align parent left
- TV5 - layout_below TV2 and right of TV4
- TV6 - layout_below TV4 and align parent left
- TV7 - layout_below TV4 and right of TV6

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation. TV1 is the first child, with gravity right and width `match_parent`. TV2 and TV3 can be contained in a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation and positioned according to weight. The remaining four `TextView`s may be similarly treated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the xml...    i hope this will be helpful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/TV1"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TV2"
          android:layout_below="@id/TV1"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TV3"
          android:layout_below="@id/TV1"
          android:layout_alignRight="@id/TV2"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TV4"
          android:layout_below="@id/TV2"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/> 
<TextView android:id="@+id/TV5"
          android:layout_below="@id/TV2"
          android:layout_alignRight="@id/TV4"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TV6"
          android:layout_below="@id/TV4"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TV7"
          android:layout_below="@id/TV4"
          android:layout_alignRight="@id/TV6"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text View 1"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="end" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text View 2"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="start" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Text View 3"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="end" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text View 4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="start" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="Text View 5"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="end" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text View 6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="start" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:text="Text View 7"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="end" />
</RelativeLayout>
```